# Credentail Provider for Windows 8

Tags: c++, windows, security, winapi, visual-c++

I need to write a Credential Provider for Windows 8. I downloaded the sample code from MSDN and build for 64-bit. The sample credential provider works fine.
I have two user accounts in my system a) Administrator and b) LocalUser1. The sample credential provider is visible only in "Administrator" selected tile. Its not loaded in "LocalUser1" account.

Please suggest what could be the problem. How can I load the credential providers for all the user accounts in current system?

Comment: Could you provide us some code? Just to narrow down the possibilities. Also check out [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @ Steve : here is the link for the MSDN sample which I have downloaded and build. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/V2-Credential-Provider-7549a730

Comment: @santhosh Could make the credential provider available for the other LocalUser1 Account? I have exactly the same problem. My Credential Provider is only visible for my Administrator account, not for any other. Thx SiS